# Spring - How to stop and start a Webserice from web application?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I would like to create a functionality for the application admin to be able to stop and start the webservice from the front end without bringing down the entire application.

The application has various other interfaces, screens and jobs which need to run all the time. The webservice alone has to be shut down for some data maintenance work and needs to be up again after it is complete. The webservice is consumed by few thirdparty applications.

Application is built with Spring 3.0.5.

I need to somehow get the webservice object(?) in the controller and trigger stop/start.

**spring-config.xml**

```
<wss:binding url="/wss/shipRequest.wss">
   <wss:service>
      <ws:service bean="#shipRequestWS">
      </ws:service>
   </wss:service>
</wss:binding>
<bean id="shipRequestWS" class="com.xxx.ShipRequestService">
   <property name="shipRequestBO" ref="shipRequestBO" />
</bean>
```

**Service**

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)
public interface ShipRequestService extends java.rmi.Remote {

          WebService methods...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most simple solutions will be adding a [JMX controlled bean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jmx.html) offering start and stop of the web service. This bean can implement the control in two types:

- Setting a flag on the injected service. The service may throw an exception on deactivated state but needs to be extended to this special behavior.
- The web service may be created by a special sub context to be loaded by the activation or stopped by deactivation. The context may be created with `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` using the current context as a parent context.

Comment: Thanks Arne. I am creating the context through ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and able to start/stop

Answer (score 0):

For "lightweight" maintenance changes, you can simply make a check on a flag at the beginning of the service methods to know if you should process the request or not.This technique is widely used for feature flipping for example.